# Firebase Console: How to see "action" event count over time

Tags: firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I'm tracking some events in my app. However, I only can see the count of "action" events in the last 30 minutes. I would like to see the count of those events in a given period of time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the "view" parameter name for your **action** event, you would need to logged a custom dimension for them to appear on your event reporting. Once you logged them on the Custom Definitions page, a data card for each parameter you logged is added to the related event-detail report. However, note that it may take up to 24 hours for the data card to appear. During this 24-hour period, you may see (not set) appear as a parameter value. Once that initial 24-hour period has passed, you will see the expected parameter values from that point forward. You may also check this documentation regarding [custom dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) for your reference.